# Using define in a conditional expression in Scheme

Tags: scheme, naming, conditional-operator

In Scheme, the general form of a *procedure definition* is:

> (define (<*name*> <*parameters*>) <*body*>)

where <*body*> accepts a sequence of expressions, allowing this kind of procedure definitions:

```
> (define (f) 1 2 3)
> (f)
3
```

Likewise, the general form of a *conditional expression* is:

> (cond (<*predicate*> <*consequent*>) (<*predicate*> <*consequent*>) … (<*predicate*> <*consequent*>))

where <*consequent*> in each clause accepts a sequence of expressions, allowing this kind of conditional expressions:

```
> (cond (#t 1 2 3))
3
```

**But why can’t I use `define` in a clause’s consequent of a conditional expression like in the body of a procedure definition?**

Compare:

```
> (define (f) (define x 1) (define y 1) (define z 1) (+ x y z))
> (f)
3
```

with:

```
> (cond (#t (define x 1) (define y 1) (define z 1) (+ x y z)))
ERROR on line 1: unexpected define: (define x 1)
```

*Note.* — I am using the Chibi-Scheme 0.8.0 implementation on MacOS 10.15.2.

Comment: This should work. The R7RS specification says that the clauses of `cond` are `expression definition* expression*`. But it seems like they're actually implementing the R6RS specification, which doesn't allow definitions at the beginning.

Comment: @Barmar Where do you see this in the spec? I see this at paragraph 4.2.1: “(⟨test⟩ ⟨expression1⟩ ...)”. Have you tried it on another R7RS compliant implementation?

Comment: My mistake. The cond clause references `<tail expression>`, not `<tail body>`.

Comment: So the reason is that definitions aren't expressions. Definitions can only be placed at certain places, like the beginning of procedure bodies and the beginning of `let` bodies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Barmar noted, *definitions* are not *expressions*, but there are two contexts where both are allowed, cf. section 5.1. of the latest specification of the Scheme programming language [*Revised<sup>7</sup> Report on the Algorithmic Language Scheme*](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) (R7RS):

- at the outermost level of a program;
- at the beginning of a body.

> A Scheme program consists of one or more import declarations followed by a sequence of expressions and definitions. Import declarations specify the libraries on which a program or library depends; a subset of the identifiers exported by the libraries are made available to the program. Expressions are described in chapter 4. Definitions are either variable definitions, syntax definitions, or record-type definitions, all of which are explained in this chapter. **They are valid in some, but not all, contexts where expressions are allowed, specifically at the outermost level of a ⟨program⟩ and at the beginning of a ⟨body⟩.**

That is why `define` is allowed in the body of a procedure definition but not in a clause’s consequent of a conditional expression since it is not a body.